# How to split a springboot multi-module maven project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, multi-module

I'm building a server using Springboot, and it will be a multi-module maven project.

I'm not sure whether I should (1) split the modules along traditional lines, e.g. have one module for the rest api, another for the domain, and another for DAO, or (2) whether i should split the modules more closely aligned to a micro-services architecture where each module contains the classes related to a single domain.

I don't have the expertise yet to build this project as a collection of pure micro-services, but my assumption is that if I take option 2 now, it would be easier in the future to split out each of the modules into individual micro-services. Whereas, with option 1 I would need to split out classes from each module to put into a single microservice.

Is my understanding correct?

Thank you

Comment: That sounds more like an architectural question than related to Maven?

Comment: Yes - it is. I wanted to get the architecture right from the beginning rather than screw it up and pay the price down the line.

Comment: practical suggestion just start.. if something is wrong later refactor it...requirement changes over the time...which might has the consequence to change architecture.. so start with the one which at the moment fits best from your point of view...

Comment: Option 1 is more of technical pattern split, if you planning to go for microservices later it is better to go with option 2